# In this program i want to extract the date in YYYY-MM-DD format from mysql database using python

Tags: python, mysql

CODE:

```
cur = sqlCon.cursor()

cur.execute("select datedue from library where member=%s ", Member.get())

row = cur.fetchone()
print(datetime.date.today())

for x in row:
    print(row)
```

But the result is in (datetime.date(2022, 12, 6),)  fromat

What should I do?????

Comment: Nothing. You got back a proper Python `datetime` object. There's no format involved. Dates in databases are binary values. They have no format. It's the same with the `datetime` object. This is no different than trying to print eg a number. If you want to *print* that `datetime` in a certain way, you need to format it. That's done using `format`, print with a format string or an f-string

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you explain how to use a format string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a date in a regular format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-a-date-in-a-regular-format)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am new to python and sql so i am confused

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `strftime()` function:

```py
cur.execute("SELECT datedue FROM library WHERE member = %s", Member.get())
row = cur.fetchone()
date_str = row["datedue"].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(date_str)
```

You could also handle this on the MySQL side by using the `STR_TO_DATE()` function:

```py
sql = "SELECT STR_TO_DATE(datedue, '%Y-%m-%d') AS datedue FROM library WHERE member = %s"
cur.execute(sql, Member.get())
row = cur.fetchone()
date_str = row["datedue"]
print(date_str)
```

Here `STR_TO_DATE()` returns a string on the database side, so no conversion would be needed in Python.