# Is there way to print date and time without creating object in OOP?

Tags: python, class, datetime, oop

```
import datetime
class date:
  def __init__(self,data):
    self.data=data
    x=datetime.date.today().year
    return x
y=date('data')
```

I tried to show data: 'todays date:26 june' but it shows `__init__() should return None, not int`. What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: That is not a standard python error.  Where, exactly, does that error come from?

Comment: If you don't want an object, why are you even making a class??

Comment: Python already has a class `date`, please don't use the same name for your class.

Comment: it is not at all clear what you are trying to do nor why you are coding a Class that does nothing useful. What is the purpose of `self.data?` Please explain better why you need more than the basic datetime functionality as in the answer from @Mohammad.

Comment: You don't want to use an object in an Object Oriented Programming (OOP) environment?

Comment: The answer is NO. Date and time objects may be categorized as “aware” or “naive” depending on whether or not they include timezone information. Everything is an object in python. But you have not create it by your own as in your example.

Answer (score 0):

The `__init__` function should always return `None` as all it does is initialise the object. Have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) for a further explanation. A solution would be to save `x` as `self.x` and then access that variable externally or if wanted, you could modify the `__new__` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
x = datetime.date.today()
print(x.strftime("Today's date: %d %b"))
```

[This will be useful for you:  How to print a date in a regular format.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-a-date-in-a-regular-format)

Comment: Unfortunately, this will create datetime.date and string objects - something OP has stated clearly that she doesn't want

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way to print **anything** in Python without creating, at the very least, a *string* object

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you are trying to do in Python. To be more specific, you said that you wanted to print the date in the format "todays date:26 june" without creating an object. To do this, you have to print a string. In Python, strings are objects of the class str. So, this is not possible.